# Accessing component property in parent controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to access a property, say `selectedItem` defined in a component from a parent controller. How to achieve this? I want to access this item so that I can open a modal defined as a partial with this. If anyone can suggest any better solution that is also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You could bind the property to a property of the controller. Something like this:

```
App.FooBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    selectedItem: null,

    // set the property somewhere in your component 
});
```

In your controller

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    fooBarSelectedItem: /* empty (null) or a value */
});
```

In your template

```
{{foo-bar selectedItem=controller.fooBarSelectedItem}}
```

Comment: I can see that you have used `fooBarSelectedItem` in controller. Is this because of any naming convention? or I can use any name?

Comment: No, that's just a name. I saw that I wrote it wrong in the template. Will correct it. You can give it any name.

Comment: Hi, if I need to do the opposite, for example accessing controller list in component, what is the best approach?

Comment: `this.get('controller')` or your controller's model/content: `this.get('controller.content')` - or a property `this.get('controller.forBarItems')` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_controller

Comment: Not working. I have set a list using model data in route object. I am creating component from that list. In my component, I have a delete button. If I click that should remove the view and view must rerender.

Comment: I had to do `get("parentView").get("controller.sugestedList")`. Is this currect approach?

Comment: I think so, but I don't know for sure. Btw, shorter: `get('parentView.controller.suggestedList')`

Comment: ok.. thanks.. Can you suggest good emeber tutorial or book? I am finding it little difficult to understand all things by myself.

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I think you have to give it time. It took me about one year to understand how it all works. Just keep asking here. Read the Ember Guide and study the API section. There's lots of good stuff there.

Comment: If the property changes in either would the other one know?

Answer (score 0):

I have a "count-down" component, which renders a clock, and when the count-down ends, I need to disable some buttons on the view around the component. The solution is similar to @splattne's answer, but it's newer Ember 3.1 syntax and the shared value is not part of the model.

Component:

```
export default Component.extend({    
    'remaining_time': computed('timer_end', 'dummy', function() {
        let now = new Date();
        let remaining = this.get('timer_end') - now;
        if (remaining < 0) {
            scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
                this.set('event_listener.expired', true);
            });
            this.set('should_run', false);
            return "Countdown Closed";
        }
       ...
    }),
});
```

Template:

```
{{count-down timer_end=model.timer_end event_listener=countdown_status}}
```

Controller:

```
export default Controller.extend({
    countdown_status: Object.create({'expired': false}),

    controls_enabled: computed('countdown_status.expired', function() {
        return !this.get('countdown_status.expired');
    }),
    ...
});
```

Note the `scheduleOnce('afterRender'`: it was necessary for https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13948. You will only need it if your component changes the shared value before the whole view is rendered, which is unfortunately what mine did.